# JavaFX : Cannot find Symbol MouseEvent

Tags: java, class, javafx, mouseevent, eventhandler

What is the correct import to pass out error `Cannot find Symbol MouseEvent` of javafx library ?

Sample error :

```
> javac Clavier.java Touche.java Gui.java 
Touche.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
  this.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
                                        ^
symbol:   class MouseEvent
location: class Touche
```

Have a nice day,

Comment: Try importing `javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent` .

Comment: @Berger Thank you so muuuch mate. I tried to find it on google but without success.. Cheers

Comment: Most IDEs have an "Organize imports" function that will show you choices for classes you have referenced but not imported (and get rid of redundant imports). In Eclipse it is Shift-Control-O (or Shift-Command-O on a Mac).

Comment: Netbeans is `Shift-Control-I`.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Berger, the answer is that i needed to import `javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent` Have a nice day!